# Cube.js server is listening on 4000, but Cannot GET UI

Tags: node.js, postgresql, pgadmin, cube.js

I try to follow this article:
https://statsbot.co/blog/angular-dashboard-tutorial-with-cubejs/

Everything looks fine, I set environments (I use postgresql DB), started cubejs server, it is listening on 4000.

> nmuser$ npm run dev
>
> ng-demo@0.0.1 dev /Users/nmuser/Analytics/ng-demo
>   node index.js
>
> Cube.js server is listening on 4000

But when I access http://localhost:4000/, there is error:

> Cannot GET /

Is anybody here who can help me? I am very new in cubjs, so please ask me question, because I am not sure what I should mention. What I miss?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means Cube.js server is running in production mode. Please unset `NODE_ENV` variable or run server in development mode explicitly:

```
$ NODE_ENV=development npm run dev
```